# C# GUI primer tutorial

Tags: c#, user-interface

Coming from Access, I am totally unfamiliar with building a GUI or even a program.

For C# application building, can someone point me to a primer or tutorial that will explain to me how to build a GUI, and what frameworks, widgets, Winforms, WPF, and everything else *are* and how they fit together to result in a usable program?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nice [tutorial of David Bolton](http://cplus.about.com/od/learnc/ss/random_2.htm).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to learn WPF instead of WinForms, you can try the [WPF tutorial of Christian Moser](http://www.wpftutorial.net/).

Answer (score 2):

[Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/winfileinfo.aspx) has a good tutorial on making a GUI if you don't have Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with "Programming Microsoft Windows with C#", by Charles Petzold.  The man is a legend at explaining GUI programming for Windows, and he does another great job in this C# edition.  He also has a book on WPF programming if you want to take that route.

Happy Learning!

Comment: But his books also dissipate a fair amount of bad practices - for instance you can find there references to improper management of Unicode (hopefully fixed now), suggestions to terminate threads as a way not to properly manage resources, the notorious misrepresentation of Hungarian notation, e.t.c.

In short - those books are useful, but beware!

Comment: @EFraim: have you read the C# version of the book?  Your comment may have been valid back when the book was targeted at C programming, but I don't buy it now.  His notation in this book is much more aligned with the .NET framework notation, and I've not seen any issues with his unicode or threading practices either.  Also, in contrast to the online tutorials recommended here, Petzold provides very deep coverage of many UI programming practices.

Comment: @Scott: No, I have not read the C# version. However the things I've seen in the C version (I believe second edition) led me to treat everything he writes with care.