# C# GUI Programming Starting

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

So....I've never really done much in the way of GUI programming apps. Namely because for school ive been stuck in C++ land. But since Im graduating in December I thought it'd be nice (while im looking for a job) to study something I've wanted to look into for awhile. And please dont mark this as "subjective" im just simply asking what I need to "know" to get started.

Namely GUI programming. Im not used to it....nor have I really ever been. It's not something they focus on in school (for instance my senior design was a webcam mouse thing, but had very little in the way of GUI)

I've seen alot about C# being the superior GUI programming tool for fast development.....but I dont really know whats out there. I know "of" QT, and Im used to C++. However Im not too familiar with what the "choice" GUI language is. I do like programming on Windows however most of my stuff has been in Unix here lately (Mostly because of my OS class).

I dont know anything about .net, and i've heard of something called WPF? Is that part of .net.....or.....what? Im just a bit confused at where to start.

Thanks

Comment: I've done some QT development on Linux, and as a GUI toolkit I found it to be easier to work with than Gtk. If you are looking to take the plunge into Windows, grab a copy of MS Visual Studio Express edition and find a good C# book - Sam's Press, O'Reilly, Apress, all good choices. The future of Windows GUI development is WPF, but it is quite different from the traditional Windows Forms development. You'll probably find more tutorials on WinForms out there, so you may want to go that route first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microsoft has some good resources for getting started on their platform with .NET.

Try these...

[Development for Beginners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/dd435692.aspx)

> Welcome to the Windows Development track. This is the best place to learn how to create software for Windows. Windows applications can take advantage of your computer's sound,  graphics, and other capabilities. You will learn how to write software for Windows XP,  Vista, or Windows Server using Visual Basic, Visual C#, or Visual C++ Express Editions.

[Ramp Up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/rampup/default.aspx)

> Ramp Up is a free, online, community-based learning program that will help you build professional development skills. Join Ramp Up (it's free!) and help advance your career...

[Creating Your First Visual C# Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383877%28VS.90%29.aspx) -
This link contains three samples:

- How to: Create a C# Console Application
- How to: Create a C# Windows Forms Application
- How to: Create a C# WPF Application

[Visual C# Guided Tour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383962%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

> The Visual C# Guided Tour presents a series of lessons that introduce you to the Visual C# Express Edition integrated development environment (IDE), creating your first application, and designing the user interface of an application.

[Learn .NET Framework on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663309.aspx)

> Start here to get a conceptual overview of the key features of the .NET Framework, including the common language runtime, the .NET Framework class library, and more.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.... C# is a great tool for GUI.... My condition was same like yours when I started.... My suggestion is get into it.... Make some simple GUIs.... Its fun to make simple apps like say Calculator!

There are very good tutorials available on internet.... You are just a Google away from them.... And For everyproblem, There is Stack Overflow! :)

All the best!!

You can check this too: [C# GUI primer tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184991/c-gui-primer-tutorial)

Comment: Lol, I like you're attitude.  + 1

Comment: @Pierreten Thanks And afterall, As they say, "You can't learn swimming by reading 'How to Swim'.... You have to jump in water!"

Answer (score 1):

WPF is pretty awesome. It is rather closely related to xml.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa663364.aspx

If you use the toolbox its mostly self explanatory for the basic components. Here are components of a basic page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531270(VS.90).aspx

Comment: I wouldn't say "WPF is closely related to xml" ... WPF uses XAML to construct its GUI, and XAML is an XML document; that's about as close as the relation gets.

Comment: Yea... thats pretty much what I meant. Syntax not rendering.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices to go with:

[Windows Forms (WinForms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bxxy49h.aspx)
[Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx)

For all future desktop GUI applications, WPF is recommended.

Comment: "For all future desktop GUI applications, WPF is recommended." I would agree with that, but if s/he is just starting to learn GUI development on Windows, I would still suggest starting with Windows Forms. I have done a substantial amount of C# GUI development, and even I have not wandered into WPF beyond a handful of tutorials at this point. The XAML may be a little much, even though VS provides a good UI editor.

Comment: Does C#/.net support both.....How do I go about choosing? Since WPF is newer are there any books specifically on it?