# I want to learn Microsoft .Net for Windows Application, where am i begin?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# GUI Programming Starting…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310442/c-gui-programming-starting)

I want my brother learn about Microsoft .Net ( Visual Studio 2008 ).
So, which one is beginning, easy for learning? Like Hello World app.

And do you know any book, ebook, or website teaching about that for beginner ?

Thanks.

I learn myself, no school at all. And I want to learn VB, not C.

Comment: not C#, I want to learn VB. Not C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a free website which can be a good starting point.

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp.html

After mastering everything here, you'll have A LOT of knowledge which will then take you from resource to resource depending on what you need to achieve with your .NET app.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks, Phil. That site have VB for me too.