# Desktop applications with C++ and .NET or other

Tags: c#, c++, desktop-application

I am trying to decide if I should put an effort towards learning C++ or C#

Right now my only background is with PHP so it doesn't matter to much which way I go.  I really liked how a lot of my favorite programs are built with C++ that just shows me how powerful it is, not to mention PHP itself is made of C.

I am hoping to build desktop applications.  From my research with C++ I would have to find a GUI library to build the desktop apps and with C# Visual Studio pretty much takes care of it for you.

Today I saw the Microsoft has a VisualC++ that uses .NET, does this mean that .NET is used as a GUI for it or do you still need a GUI library when going that route?

Please help me understand a little better as I mentioned my background is PHP and web design so this is a whole new ball park and rather overwhelming at the moment.

Any advice about the subject would be appreciated as well, thank you

Comment: For C# specifics see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310442/c-sharp-gui-programming-starting/4310477#4310477

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you would like to get out of it? Are you learning for learning sake? Trying to grow your career? Build something specific? Who would you be writing these desktop apps for? I assume you would be writing for Windows users if you are considering C#/.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is very subjective but I will answer based on your level as a beginner.

Go C#, it is easier and you will find plenty of resources and help. It is very hard to find a good beginner book or tutorial in C++.

There are very advanced topics in C#. And you can easily start a career.

Desktop application are different from web, but you find plenty of tutorials and videos. Just google it.

Answer (score 5):

(All subjective, naturally)

The Microsoft .Net stack (C#, IIS, Sql Server etc.) is very useful. You can use it to create Windows apps, websites, windows services and web services. AFAIK only Java has an equivalent level of multi-purposing so readily built in.

C++ is great but has its drawbacks.  With .Net and C# you sit on top of a runtime that for the most part won't harm performance (unless you're writing some ridiculously high-load app), handles memory management for you, includes error trapping and sandboxing.  Your apps have the capacity, out of the box, to be 'better citizens' than a C++ app. [Again, nothing in C++ stops you doing these things but there aren't so many factors taken care of for you].

C# is also a very common business language.  Most businesses use developers to solve business problems, and C++ isn't suitable for a lot of that.  Development is complicated and takes too long.  .Net better lends itself to more rapid development lifecycles because the underlying framework handles so much of the donkey-work for you.

C# - more business jobs, generally a less heavy duty programming life (yayy!  No manual garbage collection!)  Also applicable to web and windows.
C++ - more performant, more powerful (since there's no runtime limiting what you can do - wanna crash the OS? Go ahead...) but you'll have to do most things yourself.  Also no web (AFAIK).

Visual C++ is Microsoft's IDE targetting C++ on Windows. A nice user interface for you to write your software.  You can write Windows GUI software without it though and you can use Visual C++ to write console apps.

Hope that might help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you already understand pointers and are willing to invest at least 3 years to become competent, look at C++.

Otherwise, learn C#.

I've never had to used Managed C++ for anything and the few things I've read about it, very few people use it.

Comment: Managed C++ (although it's not called that anymore) is intended almost exclusively for interop purposes, to make .NET code interoperate seamlessly with native code. You shouldn't use it for anything else. I don't advise writing applications in it. If you want managed .NET code, use C#. If you want native code, use C++.